# Dynamic module imports from external function, (or - editing globals() outside of module), in Python

Tags: python, dynamic, import, module, global

I have a project in which I want to repeatedly change code in a class and then run other modules to test the changes (verification..). Currently, after each edit I have to reload the code, the testing modules which run it, and then run the test. I want to reduce this cycle to one line, moreover, I will later want to test different classes, so I want to be able to receive the name of the tested class as a parameter - meaning I need dynamic imports.

I wrote a function for clean imports of any module, it seems to work:

```
def build_module_clean(module_string,attr_strings):
    module = import_module(module_string)
    module = reload(module)
    for f in attr_strings:
        globals()[f]=getattr(module,f)
```

Now, in the name of cleanliness, I want to keep this function in a wrapper module (which will contain the one-liner I want to rebuild and test all the code each time), and run it from the various modules, i.e. among the import statements of my `ModelChecker` module I would place the line

```
from wrapper import build_module_clean
build_module_clean('test_class_module',['test_class_name'])
```

however, when I do this, it seems the test class is added to the globals in the wrapper module, but not in the `ModelChecker` module (attempting to access `globals()['test_class_name']` in `ModelChecker` gives a key error). I have tried passing `globals` or `globals()` as further parameters to `build_module_clean`, but `globals` is a function (so the test module is still loaded to the wrapper `globals`), and passing and then using `globals()` gives the error

```
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object does not support item assignment
```

So I need some way to edit one module's `globals()` from another module.

---

Alternatively, (ideally?) I would like to import the `test_class` module in the wrapper, in a manner that would make it visible to all the modules that use it (e.g. `ModelChecker`). How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Your function should look like:

```
def build_module_clean(globals, module_string, attr_strings):
    module = import_module(module_string)
    module = reload(module)
    globals[module_string] = module
    for f in attr_strings:
        globals[f] = getattr(module, f)
```

and call it like so:

```
build_module_clean(globals(), 'test_class_module', ['test_class_name'])
```

---

Explanation:

Calling `globals()` in the function call (`build_module_clean(globals()...`) grabs the module's `__dict__` while still in the correct module and passes that to your function.

The function is then able to (re)assign the names to the newly-loaded module and it's current attributes.

Note that I also (re)assigned the newly-loaded module itself to the globals (you may not want that part).